# How to disable logging in Hibernate 4.x?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to using Hibernate and have managed to get it working, but my stdout is being spammed with INFO log messages which I would like to disable. Google comes up with solutions but they are for older versions of Hibernate which don't seem to work.

Comment: Depends which backend you use for logging.  Log4j?  java.util logging?  Need more information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation: [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)

Comment: That doc is out of date and does not accurately reflect how hibernate does logging in 4.x.

Comment: And unfortunately I don't think there are up-to-date docs that cover logging.